# How non-linear equations emerge in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-system

In physics, many ODEs and PDEs are derived by applying a variational to some lagrangian density.

I more or less have a geometric interpretation of the quadratic terms of a  lagrangian and the associated linear terms in the derived ODEs or PDEs. These linear terms usually involve differential forms, exterior derivatives, ..., i.e. a variety of mathematical objects associated to the vector spaces and linear operators usually found in differential geometry.
But, I don't see how the higher order terms in the lagrangians (which usually account for interactions) can be geometrically interpreted.

As far as I can tell, the higher order terms are usually introduced in some sort of had-hoc manner, thinking in terms of perturbation theory. Namely, "free theories" (i.e. theories of non-interacting particles and waves) are modeled by the linear parts of ODEs and PDEs (and thus by the quadratic temrs of lagrangians) while interacting theories include higher-order terms into the lagrangians. How are these higher-order terms interpreted from the point of view of differential geometry?

Apologies if my question is rather vague. I am not sure how to rephrase it into more formal settings.

Comment: In the first paragraph you talked about the linear term, which I understand. But you loss me at "higher order" term. By higher order term do you mean non-linear?

Comment: In a variational principle, the quadratic terms of a lagrangian leads to a linear term in a corresponding differential equation. By higher order terms I mean cubic, cuartic, ... terms in the lagrangian, which lead to non-linear terms in the differential equation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In PDE higher order means more derivatives (for example, the laplace equation $\Delta u =0$ is second order). Thus the confusion.

Comment: Ohh, I haven't thought about that case. How about a quartic term in the lagrangian not involving any derivatives?

Comment: It seems to me that most of the interesting geometric objects in differential geometry involves non-linear quantity. For example, the Riemann curvature tensor R is a tensor which depends on the metric g in a nonlinear way. So any constraint on R would likely give you a non-linear PDE. For another example, the E-L equation for the volume functional of submanifolds is again non-linear.

Comment: Linear object (say, from Hodge theory) ultimately gives you only topological properties, but not geometric one.

Comment: For a nice example, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformed_Hermitian_Yang%E2%80%93Mills_equation
Relevant to string theory (insofar as that is considered physics), as well as mathematics.